# vba macro to create column to the right of a table

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a table called `AA_Table`, this is in a sheet called `AA`. My current vba code creates a column right next to the table, this is currently working fine. However it is cell dependant, so if my `AA_Table` has a different number of columns, then the macro doesn't do what I want it to do.

This is the current vba code:

```
Sheets("AA").Select
    Range("BY1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Hours"
    Range("BY2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "my formula goes here"
```

How could I modify this code so that it doesn't always choose cell BY2, but instead the cell to the right of my `AA_Table`

Thanks.

Comment: Will that work if my table has a different number of columns?

Comment: FYI the current code can be done in two lines `Sheets("AA").Range("BY1").Value = "Total Hours" / Sheets("AA").Range("BY2").FormulaR1C1 = "=formula"`.  Also, I'd look up how to find the lastColumn and LastRow.  Then, assign a range to your table and you can use `Range("[table range").Offset(1,0).Value =  "whatever"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to work directly with the Table/ListObject:

```
Dim lo As ListObject, lc As ListColumn

Set lo = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("myTable")

Set lc = lo.ListColumns.Add()  'append a new column

lc.Name = "MyNewName"
lc.DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-3]:RC[-1])"
```

or shorter:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns.Add()
    .Name = "MyNewName"
    .DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-3]:RC[-1])"
End with
```